# Should one feed true labels into decoder of seq2seq model?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I heard that feeding true labels speeds up training while feeding output of previous decoding step makes model more robust.

Technically speaking, is feeding the true label wrong? Can someone point me some researches about this?